# Unable to register as Facebook Developer

Tags: ios, facebook

Stackoverflow,

Is anyone else experiencing the bug on Facebook which prevents the ability to register as a Facebook Developer? The button appears greyed out for me.

[image: Unable to register.]

When I attempt to click on the button to switch the 'no' to 'yes' there is no functionality.

I have searched around the internet and on stackoverflow and have seen issues with confirmation but none with registration. I have also attempted to create a new Facebook profile and this bug continues to occur.

Any info would be greatly appreciated as implementing Facebook registration is the final step in my iOS application.

Thank you members of Stackoverflow!

I am using Chrome.

Comment: Did you verify your fb account? I'm not sure that non-verify account can access to Facebook Developer or not...

Comment: It appears that my account is verified... Still haven't found the solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

The issue was with Google Chrome... I attempted registration with Firefox and everything went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you do not want to install firefox just for registering facebook development account. In the chrome address bar, input:

```
chrome://settings/
```

Then
1. Click `'+ Show advanced settings'`
2. In the section `Privacy`. Click the button `'Content settings...'`
3. In the section `Pop-ups`. Select `Allow all sites to show pop-ups`

Done and re-try to register in fb.

---

Chromium version:   53.0.2785.143

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a browser other than chrome. Chrome has some issue with pop up. I tried with Mozilla firefox, opera, safari and explorer and it worked perfectly fine.